G4 visa application experience
Does anyone have any experience applying for the G4 visa ? I’m applying from India and I have two specific questions in mind atm

Do I have to schedule an appointment or just go the application center after receiving the sponsorship letter?
Either way, will there be need for an interview initially or I have to just drop the required documents?

Edit: It’s for a US G4

Yes it’s for a US G4

A G4 visa is for "individuals coming to the United States to take up an appointment at a designated international organization, including the United Nations, and their immediate family members." You should consult with the organization you will be taking up the appointment at. They should be familiar with the process you will need to follow.

Can you describe the research you've already done?  G-4 visas generally require a diplomatic note, not a sponsorship letter.  There is generally no interview, and applicants deal directly with a consulate or embassy, not an application center.  What organization will you be traveling for?  Are you the principal applicant or a family member?

Sorry I meant it’s a diplomatic note & organization is the World Bank. I’m the principal applicant.
They’re taking some time to get back to me so just wanted to have a better understanding beforehand. Not a lot of other info online.

Well my experience concerns applications by a UN agency officer applying for G-4 renewal in New York and Geneva, so it isn't particularly relevant, but in Geneva the agency took care of sending the application to Bern by courier and in New York the application site is across the street from the UN compound, so it's all very straightforward.  The World Bank surely ought to be able to tell you what you need to do.

This site is for short term travel like vacations. Questions about living and working abroad belong on our [expatriates.se] site.

@DJClayworth for what it's worth, the G-4 visa is also issued for short-term visits.

Okay just want to post an update.
Process was super simple. Didn’t need to apply for an appointment date or pay any visa fees. I went & gave the required documents straight at the consulate & got my visa in a couple days !

Feel free to accept your own answer.
